# lightning:recordViewForm will not load Product2 object on mobile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordviewform

I have a simple `Product2` details component.

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:attribute name="productId" type="String" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.productId))}">

        <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.productId }" objectApiName="Product2">
            <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
        </lightning:recordViewForm>

    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

**JavaScript Controller**

```
init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    let pageReference = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
    let productId = pageReference.state.c__productId;
    cmp.set("v.productId", productId);
}
```

It works when viewed via desktop, but does not load via mobile.

The `<lightning:recordViewForm` component support mobile and I've tested using the `Account` object and it worked:

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="0010w000002HsJOAA0" objectApiName="Account">
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

I also tried with a hardcoded `Product2` Id and it didn't work on mobile, but did work when viewed on desktop.

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" objectApiName="Product2">
    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

Why does it fail to work for `Product2` on mobile?

Is it possible to get it to work, or should I just use a Apex Controller?

Comment: Do you have the right FLS on the required field?

Comment: @JayantDas I assume so, because it works when viewed using a desktop browser. Or am I miss understanding something?

Comment: Oh yes, missed that part.

Comment: I cannot see v.pageReference attribute on component markup. From where you are getting it?

Comment: @sanketkumar it comes from `implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable`

Comment: i suspect problem lies with getting the id from lightning:isUrlAddressable in mobile. Can you have a try with assigning the product id in different way?

Comment: @sanketkumar I tried a hardcoded ProductID and it didn't work on mobile, but did on desktop

Comment: You are using it as a tab or app in mobile, right?

Comment: @sanketkumar there is a Product Search tab which appears in both mobile and desktop. When you click on a search result, it opens this component using `lightning:isUrlAddressable`. It all works correctly in desktop, but not on mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with lightning component, it's with Salesforce 1 mobile App.

As I can see from these 2 Ideas, Product Object is not available in Salesforce 1 Mobile App, so your `lightning:recordViewForm` would respect that and won't load it on mobile.

Please upvote these 2 ideas for support

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dn0YAAS

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxxfAAA

On digging deeper, it seems like the object who support quick action can only be supported on Mobile App

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview_global.htm&type=5

**Workaround**: Don't use Lightning Data services and use old lightning:input to show your data from product doing SOQL query in Apex.